# Weak limit of sequence of solutions of a PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence

I recently was given an exercise to complete along the lines of:

Given $u_{\lambda}$ is a weak solution of,
\begin{align}
-\Delta u_{\lambda}+\lambda mu_{\lambda}&=f\in L^{2}(\Omega)\quad f\geq 0,\\
u&=0\text{ on }\partial\Omega,
\end{align}
with $m\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{N}$ bounded and smooth and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda>0$. Show that $u_{\lambda}\rightharpoonup u_{\infty}$ in $H^{1}(\Omega)$.

My question is, can you ever expect that the weak limit of a sequence of solutions preserves the boundary conditions of weak solutions? That is, are there any conditions such that $u_{\infty}=u_{\lambda}$ on $\partial\Omega$ for all $\lambda$?

Comment: The convergence of the $u$'s is with respect to $\lambda\to+\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{u \in H^1(\Omega) | u(x)=0  \; x \in \partial \Omega \}$ is closed and convex. For this purpose, note that that the set is closed as the pre-image of $0$ under the continuous trace operator. It is also convex. By Mazurs Theorem, it is weakly closed.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this theorem. Thank you for pointing it out. However, is there also another theorem which would allow this to hold for Neumann as well as Robin boundary conditions?

Comment: There is a so-called Neumann-Laplacian (cant find a good, complete reference atm), which basically uses integration by parts to characterise the boundary values. As for the trace operator, you would requre $H^2$, which is too much regularity.